# How to reload DataTable from html code

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, datatable

here's my question, I've got a datatable in html, I have a function replacing the html code of the datatable by an updated one (the same, but with the update database values).

But the probleme is, things like "Display 1 entry from 1 to 1" doesn't update.

I'd like to refresh the whole tab with the new values, and with the data-table functions from.

Any ideas ?

I'm not really clear about how my code is; but basically : it's a html table ruled by php's foreach/if and echoes of values got by requesting a database. So, even while reloading the same html code, there won't be the same values if you add something through the database.

I'll add the fact that there is switchbuttons inside the data-base, and they get also destroy by the html reload.
When I say html reload, I mean this : `$('#myTable').html(new_html);`

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that you're using the `DataTables` plugin?  (https://datatables.net ?)  How have you configured your data source?  You can update the backing data and invoke `.draw()` on the table to re-draw it from the updated data.

Comment: Yup it's the DataTables plugin. .draw() doesn't work since I don't want to only load values, but also buttons, which are inside the DataTable, and there is one button for each rows

Comment: `.draw()` most certainly does re-draw the table, including invoking any callbacks used for customizing the rows/cells.  If you could provide an example of what you're doing and how it's failing that could help.  We can't see your code from here, and it sounds like you're using the plugin ineffectively.

Comment: May be it but the probleme is that I'm a trainee, and it's a website under construction from my enterprise, so I'm unsure if I got the right to display code in public.

Comment: So I'll try to explain the code as clearer as possible.

Comment: We can't help with code you can't show us.  If you're not allowed to show the problem to anybody outside of your organization then the help you're seeking is from within your organization.

Comment: There is currently no js values of the tab. Only php/html. The tab is directly drawn from html, following php's instructions. I'm clearly not mastering the DataTable plugin, but I tried to redraw it since I found that on the internet, but I never worked.

Comment: Alright then I understand, thx anyway for your time

Answer (score 0):

Assign your datatable initialize to variable like below

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
```

Then whenever you call your function for table reload make sure you call this function after it finish to run. It is used by datatable to refresh table.

```
table.draw();
```

Comment: I managed to fix one probleme (the "Display 1 entry from 1 to 1" now update, from destroying the last tab before drawing the new) but it destroy my BootstrapSwitches

Comment: call your bootstrapSwitch $("#myCheckBox").bootstrapSwitch() before calling table.draw()

Comment: The switch is weird, and doesn't work, I think it's just a matter of initialization, I'll try to recreate my switch manually using the parameters of bootstrapSwith();

Comment: You should approve the answer if it had a help you. If we could she the code it would have been easy to assist you.